# Does DVI to VGA monitor connection have the better display quality

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have a motherboard with a DVI port and a monitor with a VGA port.

I am currently using VGA to VGA cable.

If I change to DVI do I need a monitor with a DVI port
or will the DVI to VGA cable work better
or it will be the same as using only VGA?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, DVI-DVI would be your best bet, using a DVI-VGA adapter is a step down but both are still better than just using VGA-VGA. Having said that, the money you would spend (if it's an issue) may not be worth the increase in quality, since the difference is noticeable but isn't that significant for most applications. If you're going to spend money on a new monitor, I'd go all out and get a video card and monitor that can handle HDMI. =)

Comment: There should be no difference between DVI-VGA and just plain VGA: DVI-VGA adapters use existing analog lines in DVI-I and DVI-A connectors (which is why they won't work with DVI-D/pure digital connectors). They do not perform any active conversion from digital to analog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DVI2VGA converter as below picture and use your old VGA2VGA cable.
[image]

But for best quality better to change your monitor with new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a monitor with only a VGA connector then it only accepts VGA signals. 
There will not be a difference in quality if you use an equal quality VGA->VGA cable or an analog DVI->VGA cable.

Note that to use DVI->VGA you need a DVI option which outputs the ancient VGA signal. You can recognise those from their pin-out.

[image: DVI plug with VGA pins marked]

Also note that with a good VGA cable and a good DAC on your graphical card you can get a good clean high resolution image with VGA. However VGA is often sold on the cheaper monitors because its successor (DVI) has extra fees for the manufacturers. This is the main reason why VGA seems to be associated with poor quality.

Also, by now [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) has its own successor: [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).