# Quality issues with 1 DVI Monitor and 1 VGA Monitor

Tags: vga, dvi

I have a laptop that has one DVI-D port and one VGA port. I can use two monitors using one port each but the problem is that there is significant quality issues when using the two side by side. By using an adapter, is it possible to make the VGA into the same high quality DVI-D port? Or will there still be quality issues/issues with my laptop's video card?

Edit// Sorry, my laptop does not have one of each, but my work laptop is connected to this black thing that has one of each and connects to the monitors.

Comment: Are you comparing 2 identical-model monitors, and have you tried switching them between VGA/DVI inputs to ensure the quality issue isn't inherent to one of the monitors?

Comment: You state you have quality issues when using the monitors "side-by-side." Does this mean that the issues go away when you use only one or the other monitor alone? Also, what sort of connection does the "black thing" use to connect to your laptop? Edit your question to include the make/model # of that device if available.

Comment: I believe its a docking port. It's at my office workstation so I'm not familiar with the model If you use the monitors by itself you wouldn't notice that there's a difference in quality. The difference is relative so only appartent with used side by side. And yes, I've tried switching them. I know that there are quality differences between VGA and DVI just asking how should I resolve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to make the VGA into the same high quality DVI-D

No, not really.

Your computer generates **digital** information, then it either:

- Outputs that to a monitor without quality loss ([DVI-D](https://superuser.com/questions/558795/does-dvi-to-vga-monitor-connection-have-the-better-display-quality), HDMI or Display port)
- Or translated it into analog, transmits that and translated that back as good as possible (VGA and DVI-A).

Your VGA output is analog. It has already been translated and some quality is lost.  You might be able to immediately convert if back to digital format but you will always have some loss.

As to your problem (but not the question):

- VGA is ancient. Are you sure that the VGA monitor is not simple much older and has poorer quality?
- For VGA the cable quality is important. How good is the cable?
- Lastly: You might be able to connect two displays to the DVI's output with high quality (E.g. via a [Matrox dualhead](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/?utm_campaign=DH2Go_SE_PR&utm_medium=PR&utm_source=PR)) or you could add a low performance USB graphics card with DVI output.

Comment: Both monitors are new and the same model. Both came with a VGA and DVI connector. Problem is, my laptop does not have two DVI ports. The cable I have is whatever came with my monitor. But the quality is so drastic when putting the two side by side, will getting a VGA to DVI adapter improve things at all? I didn't want to buy it and then it end up not working.

Comment: It depends on the cause and metrial you get. But probably: No.

Comment: BTW, which laptop do you have? IS there a docking station (with multiple monitor outputs) for it? Are you sure it does not have display port (the successor for DVI, which allows daisy changing monitors).  I expect the answer to be "no, consumer laptop with no docking option" and "no display-port and no DP monitors", but I should ask before assuming.

Comment: I have a lenovo thinkpad with a docking station. It's my office workstation so I'm not exactly sure what model. But yes, it has multiple monitor outputs just not any two of the same. One is VGA and one is DVI. Yes it has a display port. Will getting an adpater for the display port solve all my problems?

Comment: If you can use both Docking DVI to monitor DVI and dockign DP to docking DP (or via a convertor docking DP to DVI); then yes. It should solve it.  I had the same problem at work and I am now running DVI->DVI and DP->DP with my VGA connector left empty. (On an HP elitebook).